# Moto x 2nd gen mhl support retrieve data broken screen

Tags: debugging, screen

I have a moto x 2nd gen and the screen is broken. I want to retrieve my data from the phone (documents, pictures, videos and stuff). USB Debugging was not turned on and the USB connection was set to charging.

Can anyone help me how to get my data back? The Phone is stock android on Marshmallow. I can feel the vibrations on the screen meaning the phone is working but I can't see anything except some green light. I am not sure if this phone supports MHL output so that I can mirror the screen to my TV and turn on the debugging mode.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is mainly for problems that involve code. Like you have a piece of code that doesn't work for a specific language.

Post this question on device specific forums or websites. Search for Moto x forums or websites and try asking there.